How to resolve discrepancy between simulated and analytical diffusive particle statistical behaviour in one-dimension?
Assume a scenario where a Brownian particle with diffusion coefficient $D$ is emitted in a 1-D environment from $z=d$, the reflecting wall is at $z=0$, we know analytically that the PDF of such a particle is given by:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi D t} }\exp\big(-\frac{(z-d)^2}{4Dt})+\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi D t} }\exp\big(-\frac{(z+d)^2}{4Dt})$$
Now, I am using this code in MATLAB to simulate the particle behaviour and then use kernel density to generate its pdf:
clear all;
close all;
clc;
D=4*10^-11;
d=20*10^-6;
R=2*10^-6;
timeT=d^2/(6*D);
loopz=0;
for N=1:1:10^7%number of particles
z=d;
for tau=0:(1*10^-5)*timeT:timeT+((1*10^-5)*timeT)
k = sqrt(2*D*tau); 
dz = k*  randn(1,1);
z_prev=z;
z= z+dz;
if(z<=0)
 z=z_prev;
end
if(tau>=timeT && tau<=timeT+(1*10^-5)*timeT)
loopz=loopz+1;
z_pos(loopz)=z;
break;
end
end
end
x_distance = linspace(0,1*10^-4);
[f,xi] = ksdensity(z_pos,'Function','pdf');
plot(x_distance,f,'o');

Furthermore, analytically I generate the PDF using the aforementioned equation for the same set of values. The the two pdfs have a huge difference in magnitudes. Moreover, on normalizing the simulated PDF I got the comparison graph as follows, where the first figure is the comparison of simulated and analytical PDFs where magnitude normalization is done for simulated PDF. The second figure is the comparison of two CDFs with out any normalization.


My question is even after taking as large iterations as <$8\times 10^6$ for simulations why I am not able to get a perfect matching even of CDFs or PDFs?

I think your particle might be getting stuck to the wall (or rather a short distance away from it). If I'm understanding your code right, you simply remain at the same point if your step would put you behind the wall. Near the wall, roughly 50% of your steps would be behind. I think instead of rejecting steps past the wall, you should reflect them, taking any excess and moving in the opposite direction. This should push the probability further away from the wall.

@Tyberius Do you mean to say that not only should I return the particle to the previous location but also move further away from the reflecting wall, as much as I would have moved inside the wall if no wall was present?

Yes, move as far away from the wall as you would have moved into the wall.
